# Zend Framework 2: Executing a SQL query using an Adapter

Tags: zend-framework2, firebird

I am just beginning to use Zend Framework and starting to understand how it works. I have checked the official documentationa and followed several tutorials and most of the examples I have found are quite basic: one or 2 tables (at most) are used in the application and one model is created for each one. No problem there, but right now I am working in a real application where I get my data from a complex sql query that includes several tables (5 to be precise) and one stored procedure. I honestly have no idea on how to proceed with this or even where to start trying.

Should I create a model for each table involved in the query (5 of them), even when I only need 1 or 2 fields from some of them and then try to make a select that works? or
Should I create a view on the database (doesn´t sounds so good with the stored procedure) and then base the model on that view? or
Should I use a ORM to make my life easier? If so, do you know of any that works properly with Firebird? or do I have no idea and I should do something totally different to those things I mentioned?

**UPDATE**

By Will's suggestion and checking in Zend's documentation I decided to use an Adapter to make the query directly in SQL format, but it is not quite working yet. What i have so far in my controller is this:

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
```

...

```
 public function indexAction() {
    $db = new DbAdapter(array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'firebird:host=127.0.0.1;port=3050;dbname=C:\\wamp\\www\\Reports\\data\\THdata.GDB',
    'username' => 'SYSDBA',
    'password' => 'masterkey' ));    

    $sql = 'SELECT SELITE FROM TILIKAUSI WHERE COMPANYID = 1'; //I am starting with a simple query first.      
    $sql_result = $db->createStatement($sql, array(125000, 125200))->execute();
    if($sql_result->count() > 0){
    $results = new ResultSet();
    $this->view->data = $results->initialize($sql_result)->toArray();
    }
    return $this->view;
    }
```

The result is an error like `Creating default object from empty value in (Controller path, line:  $this->view->data =  $results;)`

It seems like no values are being returned. Is this an appropiate way of doing this query or am I missing something? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using DoctrineORM based modules can help out a lot with stuff like this, however sometimes I prefer to stay away from them to streamline my application a bit more performance wise.  For complex sql queries like the one you listed I generally just use the SQL adapter that ships with zf2.

Add the following use clause to your class:

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
```

An example is something like this:

```
$adapter = new Adapter(array('driver' => 'mysqli',
 'host' => 'localhost',
 'port' => '3306',
 'dbname' => 'test',
 'username' => 'test',
 'password' => 'test'));
 $list = $adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->execute('Add your complex query as you currently have it');
```

When the data is returned you will be able to do a standard foreach loop on the $items array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had been trying to make it work with the adapter (checking the zend documentation too), but I keep getting some errors, I don't know if it's due to the adapter configuration or the query. What I get is a `PDOException`. To configurate the adapter I use the same parameters I have in the config files global and local (which are working) and then in my controller I add `use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;`. I tried with a simplier query, but doesn't wotk either. am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using pdo_mysql driver?  If so the syntax is slightly different from what I posted above.

Comment: No, I am using pdo_firebird. I already have an adapter configured in the `global` and `local` files in `config/autoload` and it is working, so I just copied the same syntax into the controller. I guess there must be a way to call that adapter, instead of declaring it again. But I don't think the problem is the adapter because the warning I get is `Creating default object from empty value` in the controller. I updated the information above with the code I am using (I guess I might not be doing it properly), any ideas?

Comment: It is working now :D. I used ResultInterface & ResultSet components to handle the data resulting from the query. But I still, I don't feel comfortable calling the adapter this way in the controller... Do you happen to know another way to do it?

Comment: You're going to have to do a di injection of the adapter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988697/zf2-config-from-module-with-no-controllers  is another post I recently did where I wanted to have my config in a module instead of doing di with a controller.  The same principle applies when injecting configuration or adapters for instance.